# Droptree fails on certain items

Tags: content-editor

I've got a strange error with a droptree field, it works for all items except those below a certain folder, as below.

[image]

Debugging with Chrome the last request before the null item is returned was to the content editor with a massive query string, and when i browsed to it i got an IIS error about querystring length, so i changed the `web.config` settings as below:

```
 <system.webServer>
 <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"  maxQueryString="65536" maxUrl="65536" />
      </requestFiltering>
</security>
  </system.webServer>
```

and

```
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="512000"  maxQueryStringLength="65536" maxUrlLength="65536" />
```

still getting the issue, any ideas?

Sitecore 8.2 initial release

Comment: Have you tried browsing to that item in Content Editor and trying to select it there to see how many versions in current language it has?

Comment: it happens for any item under the "courses" folder, even  newly created item with any template

there are a large number of items in that folder, so I am thinking it relates to that

Comment: Well, I can tell you what it's not. It's not directly related to the number of items under `courses`. At least not on 8.2u2. I created an item with 25.000 items under it, and had no issue other than a bit of load time. Droptree picked it up fine.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, Have you resolved this issue? then please let me know.

Comment: Can you create another folder and add a large number of new items? As @MarkCassidy has pointed out - that doesn't seem to be the issue and would eliminate it. Also, can you try recreating your `courses` folder and see what happens?